# Doctrine 1.2 models returning integer fields as string values using Zend Framework and MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, types, doctrine-1.2

Any idea why my Doctrine 1.2 models are returning *string* values for *integer*-defined fields?

Base model defined as:

```
abstract class Kwis_Model_Base_User extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('user');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'unsigned' => true,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));

        // more fields
        // ...
    }
```

Table Model is defined as:

```
class Kwis_Model_UserTable extends Kwis_Model_BaseTable
{

    /**
     * Returns an instance of this class.
     *
     * @return object Kwis_Model_UserTable
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        $table = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Kwis_Model_User');
        return $table;
    }

    // other methods
    // ...
}
```

Sample controller code:

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $userTable = Kwis_Model_UserTable::getInstance();
        $user = $userTable->find(1);
        echo "<pre>" . var_dump($user->id) . "</pre>"; die();
    }
}
```

Produced output:

```
 string '1' (length=1)
```

Any ideas, greatly appreciated. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also as an answer to below, bitwise operations on strings left- and right-hand will operate on the ASCII value.

You can cast int as int using a hydration listener. Either create a new hydration listener and add it to the record(1), or just use the existing hook templates in the record object(2).

1: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/pl#record-listeners

2:

```
   abstract class My_Rec extends Doctrine_Record {
    function postHydrate($event) {
        $data = $event->data;
        $data['status'] = (int) $data['status'];
        $event->data = $data;       
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Whether I do it at the record level via hydrators and/or listeners or at the field level with standard getXXX/setXXX accessors/mutators is something I'll have to consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the benefit of using typeless variables in PHP? What problem is this causing? You can still do mathematic operations on it if you want. Although, I would suspect that you'd never need to do any actions on a user ID other than string comparison.

Comment: Well, it is forcing me to be a little more careful in the equality checks that I use. I find that I am doing (int) casts more often than I want (probably better to write custom getXXX/setXXX methods on for the model to do those casts). But generally, I'm just a little surprised since the hasColumn() method on the base model specifies the type. As you imply, it's not a critical issue; just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong - which is usually the explanation ;-)

Comment: If you selecting IDs from MySQL and trying to pass it to MongoDB as "WHERE" condition, it DEFINATELY causes a troubles! Because if MongoDB field contains integer and you pass string, the clasue will fail.